# не видит модуль nnfs при импорте

Tags: python, импорт

Читаю книгу про нейронные сети. Дочитал до момента где требуются готовые входные данные. Установил библиотеку и импортировал `import nnfs`, выдало ошибку `>>> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nnfs'`. Проверял библиотеку, вижу она установлена, перезагрузил пк, всё равно выдало ошибку. Как решить проблемы увы не знаю.

[image]

Пытался удалять и устанавливать библиотеку, всё равно не помогло

Comment: Может, вы запускаете в venv, а там нет nnfs

Comment: `from nnfs.datasets import spiral_data_generator`

Comment: В общем, я запускал jupyter-lab через анаконду. Друг посоветовал попробовать запустить jupyter-lab через консоль. Установил, запустил и всё сработало. Видимо у меня установлены две разные версии python, т.к.  я недавно обновлял версию и походу сменился путь установки библиотек. Ну или я просто не знаю в чём причина